# Jquery Datatables column rendering and sorting objects

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables column rendering with an object for data and everything works except sorting.

```
{
    "title": "Tasks",
    "data": "TasksSourceLocations",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var name = data.Task.DisplayName;
        ret += "<img src='/Images/Icons/trev.jpg'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + name;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

TaskSourceLocations looks like this:

```
SourceLocationId: 1255
Task: {DisplayName: "Trev"}
```

The key thing is the text the user sees is data.Task.DisplayName and that's what I want to sort on.

However when I click on the column heading to sort I end up sorting by

TasksSourceLocations asc

The reason for this is my server-side method can only sort by single columns. It looks like this.

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyDataTablesRequest<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DtRequest dtReq)
{
    query = query
        .OrderBy(dtReq.Columns[dtReq.Order[0].Column].Data + " " + dtReq.Order[0].Dir)
        .Skip(dtReq.Start)
        .Take(dtReq.Length);
}
```

DtRequest is a general-purpose class used by several pages which use DataTables.

```
public class DtRequest
{
    public ColumnInfo[] Columns { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public OrderInfo[] Order { get; set; }
    public SearchInfo Search { get; set; }
}
```

Should I doing something different client-side or server side?

Comment: If you're doing server-side processing, ordering must be implemented on the server-side as well, see [serverSide](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide). For example, you can modify your script so that if `dtReq.Columns[dtReq.Order[0].Column].Data` equals to `TasksSourceLocations` replace it with desired column to sort.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the end by doing something different on the server side for this column. It was either that or creating an invisible column on the client-side and sorting by that behind the scenes.